# Is it possible to limit ammount of concurrent builds in Travis-CI

Tags: travis-ci, saucelabs

We use Travis-Ci with OpenSauce to test our web application. OpenSauce has a limit for concurrent running of tests - 2 tests. Travis-CI by default can run much more build/tests in parallel. As the result of different limits our builds fail randomly.

So, is it possible to set limit for amount of parallel running builds on Travis-CI side?

Comment: To me it looks like Sauce is putting jobs into queue, so it will just take longer to test (though I really did not investigate more deeply).

Answer (score 5):

On the Travis CI project on GitHub there's an issue open about limiting the concurrent builds per project: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1366

Comment: The feature is already implemented in Travis-CI settings UI.

Answer (score 0):

The [number of concurrent jobs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#limiting-concurrent-jobs) for a repository can be easily restricted by Travis-CI user interface in repository settings field `Limit concurrent jobs`.

[image: Limiting Concurrent Jobs]